# Is the ideal $I := (7X+14, X^3+2X^2+1) \subseteq \mathbb Z[X]$ prime? Is it maximal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The question is fully contained in the title.

I tried to prove maximality (if that happens, $I$ is prime as well) in $\mathbb Z[X]$, but I am not able to figure a strategy out for that purpouse. Obviously, if $I$ is not maximal, I am expected to say whether $I$ is a prime ideal, which is a problem too.

How would you solve such exercise?

Comment: What is the ring? The answer is dependent on that.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just noticed I made an omission (it is a part of a larger exercise). Pardon. ^-^'

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is euclidian, I is generated by $f(x):=gcd(7x+14,x^3+2x^2+1)$. If f is irreducible, then it is also prime. And if $f \neq 0$, then $I=(f)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $I$ contains $\;7(X^3+2X^2+1)-X^2(7X+14)=7$, hence
$$\mathbf Z[X]/I\simeq \mathbf Z/7 \mathbf Z[X]/(I/7 \mathbf Z[X])= \mathbf Z/7 \mathbf Z[X]/(X^3+\bar 2X^2+\bar 1).$$
Can you show that $X^3+\bar 2X^2+\bar 1$ is irreducible in $ \mathbf Z/7 \mathbf Z[X]$?

Comment: No. How do you?

Comment: It's quite simple (and a bit tedious): if it is not irreducible, as it has degree $3$, it has a root in $\mathbf F_7=\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3\}$ . Just test if any of these is a root.

Comment: Well, that is far from my knowledge: what is $\mathbf F_7$? Nor I am aware of the theorem you just mentioned. :?

Comment: $\mathbf F_7$ denotes the field with $7$ elements. It is just $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z$, but is shorter to type. As to the irreducibility  question,  a reducible *cubic* polynomial has at least one linear factor, simply for degree reasons. It is more an observation than a theorem.

Comment: Ah yes, I got it now. I just misundestood "your" notations. Thank you.

Comment: I love "my" notations. I'll have to think of copyrighting them…  Happy new year!

Comment: No no, it was all my fault, ignorance. I imagined $\mathbf F_7$ is something strange and this bewildered me, but it's pretty simple and, I see now, and common. Happy new year you too.

Answer (score 4):

Let's just play around and see what kinds of polynomials we can find in $I$.

First of all, we can try to cancel the cubic term from the cubic generator, and we see that
$$
7(X^3+2X^2+1)-X^2(7X+14)=7
$$
is an element of the ideal. And since $7X+14=7(X+2)$, we get
$$
I=(7,X^3+2X^2+1)
$$
which is a lot simpler.

Now what? Well, since we have a constant in our ideal, it is apt to use the third isomorphism theorem. It states that we can divide out by one generator at a time (presumably you know all the basic connections between ideals and the corresponding quotients).

So if we're interested in whether $(7,X^3+2X+1)\subseteq \Bbb Z[X]$ is maximal or prime, we might just as well look at $(X^3+2X^2+1)\subseteq \Bbb Z[X]/(7)$. And therefore we can just check whether $X^3+2X+1$ has any roots modulo 7. If it does have roots the ideal isn't prime, and if it doesn't have roots, then the ideal is prime and also maximal (because $\Bbb Z[X]/(7,X^3+2X+1)$ would then be a finite integral domain and therefore a field, or alternatively because the quotient is a degree 3 extension of the field $\Bbb Z_7$).